# RewriteRule 2 parametros .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

tengo la siguiente url

```
http://localhost/web/play.php?pk=567429&c=hd
```

y en el archivo .htaccess tengo esto

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)$ play.php?pk=$1&c=$2 [L]
```

Al ponerlo de esta forma si funciona, pero necesito agregarle un segundo parámetro es que **C**

> http://localhost/web/play/567429

pero de esta forma no funciona

> http://localhost/web/play/567429/sd

Ya que me da el siguiente error:

"Error 404 Objeto no localizado"

Comment: RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ play.php?pk=$1&c=$2 [QSA,L]

fijate de esta forma

Comment: No funcionó, ahora no funciona cuando entro a web/play/67429